# IE10 and IE11 SCRIPT5 Acess is Denied error when attempting a CORS request using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: internet-explorer, cors

I'm not using jquery, just vanilla javascript.  My site is hosted on a domain, let's say it's example.com

When running the following code:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://www.example2.com', true);
```

I get an error:

> SCRIPT5: Access is denied

This code works fine in other browsers (chrome, safari).

Also, this only seems to break when running it on my site.  When I run that snipped of code from the IE 11 console, on other sites around the web, the error does not occur.

Do I need to set any specific headers on the site that's hosting the script? Or on the site that's loading the script?

Comment: *"Do I need to set any specific headers on the site that's hosting the script"* No. *"Or on the site that's loading the script"* Yes. Are you sure you aren't running in IE compatibility mode?

Comment: Are you going from http to https?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured out the reason, it was very odd, and because of some crappy legacy code sitting on the site!

This meta tag existed in the header:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

Which was telling IE to run as IE9, and IE9 has a different mechanism for doing cross-domain requests.

Answer (score 1):

I can use XMLHttpRequest as follows:

```js
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', 'http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/cdtest/test2011060701.xml', false);
req.send();
var xml = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(req.responseXML);
console.log(xml);
```

The directory on the server is configured to allow any requests from other origins, sending the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` response header.

I tested with Firefox, Chrome and IE on Windows 8.1.

Comment: On which server? The server responding to the request, or the server hosting the page that made the request?

Comment: The server responding to the request. Try the snippet I posted with developer tools open in your browser to inspect the request and response headers.

Comment: The thing is, it the request never even gets to that server, the SCRIPT5 error happens instantaneously when it invokes "open"

Comment: Does the snippet I posted not work for you? With which browser(s)? It works fine for me with Firefox 33, Chrome 39 and IE 11 on Windows 8.1. Include a snippet in your question that does not work, so that we can try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: The snippet does not work for me.  It's on IE10 and 11 in Windows 7. I posted the snippet in my original question.

Comment: Well, Stackoverflow allows you to include executable code snippets, so please do that, then others can reproduce the problem hopefully.

Comment: I made it runnable - but it needs to be run from within the console, on the site where it's hosted.  This error does not occur on every site, but only when running that code from that site.

Comment: So `XMLHtmlHttpRequest` is what you call runnable? Oh well.

Comment: My apologies, fixed the spelling.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I faced this issue because of the wrong URL images but they are displayed fine in Chrome, but not IE.
Example:

```
http:////www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png
```

is displayed in Google Chrome (please copy and paste it) but is not displayed in my IE.

Reason why: the URL above actually contains more than just two slashes. Hey, I have a typo in my URL! Just fix it!